# run exec() command as many times as the lines of txt file

Tags: php, batch-processing, sox

i'm using Sox (Sound eXchange) library to convert .wav file into .flac.
If i use the terminal, it works good:

```
$Brus:~ pum$ sox outputFolder/file/file.000.wav flac/file.000.flac
```

and the file file.000.flac was converted into the flac folder rightly.

Also inside my script, if i run:

```
         exec('sox/sox outputFolder/file/file.000.wav flac/file.000.flac');
```

the conversion works good.

My problem now, is that i need to convert a batch of file. I create a txt file with the list of files .wav (listWav.txt) to be converted, and i want to run the "exec()" command as many time as there are lines with the file name in the "listWav.txt" file.

This is the listWav.txt file:

```
outputFiles/file/file.000.wav
outputFiles/file/file.001.wav
```

This is the listFlac.txt file:

```
file.000.flac
file.001.flac
```

This is the code i wrote trying to run "exec()" command as described:

```
//read all txt files content
$file2 = fopen("listFlac.txt","r");
$file3 = fopen("listWav.txt", "r");
//loop the file and read it line by line
while(! feof($file2) && ! feof($file3)){
  $tt = fgets($file2);
  $tt2 = fgets($file3);
  //run sox conversion
  exec('sox/sox' . ' ' . $tt2 . ' ' . 'flac/' . $tt);
}
fclose($file2);
fclose($file3);
```

If i print_r('sox/sox' . ' ' . $tt2 . ' ' . 'flac/' . $tt); this is the result:

```
sox/sox outputFiles/file/file.000.wav flac/file.000.flac sox/sox outputFiles/file/file.001.wav flac/file.001.flac
```

so the loop of the "exec()" command was executed as many times as the lines of the file "listWav.txt", but it doesn't work properly because only "file.001.flac" was generated, so i understand that the while loop allow "exec()" to take only the end line of the "listWav.txt" file, and run it.

Does anybody know what i have to edit in my script to run "exec()" the number of times for all the files in the list?

EDIT: I solved in this way, i splitted the while in two while nested and called two equivalent "exec()" command. The code could be not elegant but it works for my purpose.

```
while(! feof($file2)){
  $tt = fgets($file2);
    while (!feof($file3)) {
      $tt2 = fgets($file3);
      exec('sox/sox' . ' ' . $tt2 . ' ' . 'flac/' . $tt);  
    }
      exec('sox/sox' . ' ' . $tt2 . ' ' . 'flac/' . $tt); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `file` function instead, and add a counter to your loop.

```
$flacArray = file("listFlac.txt");
$wawArray = file("listWav.txt");
$i=0;
foreach ($flacArray as $flac) {
    $wavInfo = pathinfo($wawArray[$i]);
    exec('sox/sox' . ' ' . $flac . ' ' . 'flac/' .  $wavInfo["basename"] . str_pad($i, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) .".wav");
    $i++;
}
```

**NOTE**: This is works only for 999 file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will use your code in another part of my project. About my question, i solved by myself and posted the solution.